# Domain registration for decentralized application

Tags: blockchain, decentralization

I have a question I can not find any answer to.

I understand that through blockchain, ethereum, some decentralized applications can be made. My question is, how can these applications be accessed? If such an application is accessed online, the .com domain is not owned by a person who has full access to it?

Comment: I'm also looking for decentralized domain service, just wrote a blogpost about it: https://steemit.com/decentralizeeverything/@genesisre/the-need-for-decentralized-domain-registrar-parallel-internet

Answer (score 3):

An Ethereum decentralized application (DApp) is typically a web application (so, written in HTML, CSS, and Javascript) that knows how to communicate with Ethereum nodes (using the Web3.js library, or directly using the [JSON-RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC)). Each DApp likely is programmed by the developer(s) to communicate with one or several smart contracts that the developers already deployed into the Ethereum blockchain. In that way, a DApp serves as a friendly UI for a specific smart contract.

So, to the question of where the DApp is accessed from, the developer of the application can deploy it to a number of places. It can either be distributed as a downloadable (and the user runs the HTML file locally), hosted on a web server (on a ".com" domain or similar, or on a Tor node), or stored in IPFS and run from there.

Comment: @Barti Sure thing! If that answer helped, making it as "correct"will help others in the future see it too.